# Labeling bar plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Could someone, please help me with the labeling bar plot on their above? I created a bar plot and the columns are colored with a different color but because of having a lot of colors, it is very hard to define which color belongs to which column. That is why I thought it is better also label the bar above them to see that which color represents which column. Or if you have a better idea please share it with me.  My graph:

[image]

The code I used:

```py
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Default, only 10 different colors are used. You seem to have 31 categories, and no colormap has that many sufficiently different colors. Anyway, such a stacked bar graph doesn't look suitable for this many categories. Adding more labels would just make it more chaotic. You might want to group categories together and display those groups. Perhaps, you could try to assign a principal color to each group, and have different tints within such group.  Such an approach highly depends on what the data signifies, and what you want to show.

Comment: I suggest reducing greatly the number of categories by grouping those of less significance together in an 'other' group. Also, readability could be improved by using instead a [stacked area chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stackplot_demo.html).